# Not able to create Project Web App Site- Project Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I have install Project server 2010 on application server. SharePoint is already installed on same. 
Now when I am trying to create Project Web App site I am getting below error:

> Failed to provision site PWATest with error: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8107058A): 0x8107058aThe security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

I have followed below article to install Project Server 2010
http://epmcentral.com/articles/ps10/ps10installsteps.php

Please share your thoughts and useful links for the Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration->Application Management->[your web application]->General Settings->General Settings, in Web Page Security Validation, increase the Web Page Security Validation(default is 30 mins):
[image]

After that, try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried with after increasing the Security validation setting to 60 minutes and got the same error.
I will be able to create the PWA site on another web application and facing this issue for default web application that is on port 80.

Comment: please compare the difference between the problematic web application and the working web application.